# Pointers as member variables to a class/dynamic memory in classes

Tags: c++, class, pointers, dynamic

Suppose we have the following which makes a 10 x 10 2-Dimensional array and sets the first cell to 100:

```
class twoD{
    int **p = new int*[10];
public:
    twoD(){
        *p = new int[10];
        p[0][0] = 100;
    }
};
```

Why is this ok when the following is not.

```
class twoD{
    int **p = new int*[10];
    *p = new int[10];
public:
    twoD(){
        p[0][0] = 100;
    }
};
```

Comment: Surely this has nothing to do with "2d arrays". Or pointers.

Comment: Neither of those really ends up with a properly initialized 2d array. You really want your constructor to do something like: `for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { p[i] = new int[10]; }` and you better have a destructor to match, or you'll be leaking memory all over the place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in the second case "*p = new int[10];" is not a variable declaration and hence can not be in the class definition.